# Input Type Radio Button Undefined Index

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

```
$sel="";
$suc="";
$gend="";
$male="";
$female="";
$selected_radio="";
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $e=0;
    $selected_radio = $_POST['gender'];
    if($selected_radio!="")
    {
      if ($selected_radio == 'male')
      {
        $male = 'checked';
      }
      else if ($selected_radio == 'female')
      {
        $female = 'checked';
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $sel="Select Your Gender";
      $e=1;
    }
    if($e==0)
    {
      $suc="Success";
      $male ="";
      $female ="";
    }
}
```

Without selecting option/radio button, when i click "save" (Submit button)., it showing **"Undefined index: gender"**. But error msg also appearing *"Select Your Gender"*. When i select any one option(Male/Female), its successfully appearing msg.(*"Success"*). 
So Please help me to find the solution

Comment: It simply means gender is not getting set when you select nothing.

Comment: If radio / checkbox is not selected its not sent as POST key.. even if your POST['save'] isset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $sel="";
    $suc="";
    $gend="";
    $male="";
    $female="";
    $selected_radio="";
    if(isset($_POST['save']) && isset($_POST['gender']))
    {
     $e=0;
     $selected_radio = $_POST['gender'];

      if ($selected_radio == 'male')
      {
       $male = 'checked';
      }
      else if ($selected_radio == 'female')
      {
       $female = 'checked';
      }

   }
    else
    {
    $sel="Select Your Gender";
    $e=1;
    }
    if($e==0)
    {
    $suc="Success";
    $male ="";
    $female ="";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you the radio button/ checkbox is not selected/checked the particular value is not passed in the `$_POST` global array.

You can use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check whether the particular value is set. `isset($_POST['gender'])`

Answer (score 1):

Change `if(isset($_POST['save']))`
to
`if(isset($_POST['save']) && isset($_POST['gender']))`